# Como efetuar o parse de XML com namespace e prefixo em PHP utilizando SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, parser, namespace, simplexml

O arquivo dados.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp status="ok">
<ArrayOfContact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Contact>
        <Date xmlns="XYZ.GetContacts.Contact">2015-03-25T15:34:11.917</Date>
        <ContactDetail xmlns:q1="XYZ.GetContacts.Contact.Detail.Chat" xsi:type="q1:Chat" xmlns="XYZ.GetContacts.Contact">
            <q1:Browser>Chrome</q1:Browser>
            <q1:Platform>Windows 7</q1:Platform>
            <q1:Date>25/03/2015 15:34:11</q1:Date>
            <q1:Dialog>
                <q1:Messages>
                    <q1:Message>
                        <q1:Description>&lt;![CDATA[Olá Fulano de Tal, em que posso ajudar?]]&gt;</q1:Description>
                        <q1:MessageSource>AGENT_TO_USER</q1:MessageSource>
                    </q1:Message>
                    <q1:Message>
                        <q1:Description>&lt;![CDATA[kauan]]&gt;</q1:Description>
                        <q1:MessageSource>USER_TO_AGENT</q1:MessageSource>
                    </q1:Message>
                </q1:Messages>
            </q1:Dialog>
        </ContactDetail>
    </Contact>
</ArrayOfContact>
</rsp>
```

Com o script PHP abaixo, efetuo o parse do arquivo XML, e consigo obter os valores, por exemplo, dos elementos **q1:Browser** e **q1:MessageSource**

```
<?php
$file = "dados.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$namespaces = $xml->ArrayOfContact->Contact->ContactDetail->getNameSpaces(true);
$qN = $xml->ArrayOfContact->Contact->ContactDetail->children($namespaces['q1']);

echo "q1:Browser --->  {$qN->Browser} <br />";
echo "q1:MessageSource ---> {$qN->Dialog->Messages->Message->MessageSource}";
```

- Como eu consigo obter o valor do prefixo **xsi:type** do elemento **ContactDetail**?
- Como obter o texto de um dos elementos **q1:Description** que está entre `&lt;![CDATA[ ]]&gt;`?